# variable speed drive interfering with distant PHEV charger

Tags: interference, emi-filtering, power-filtering

I am using a generic variable speed drive for a water pump.
About 5% of the time that I run it, it stops my BMW 530e PHEV from charging. What is the most likely cause? What measurements can I make to confirm?

Both the variable speed drive and the PHEV have their own dedicated circuits, and they are 20 feet apart from each other. The variable speed drive has the following specs:

- 240VAC single phase input, 10A fuse
- full bridge rectifier input (yes, the poor power factor type)
- add-on input reactor: [2mH x 4, 7.5A](http://catalog.triadmagnetics.com/Asset/CMT908-V1.pdf) per line (16mH total)
- 1.5HP, 240VAC three phase output, 5A fuse per phase
- add-on output reactor: [12mH x 4, 4A](http://catalog.triadmagnetics.com/Asset/CMT-8111.pdf) per line (96mH total)

I realize that these are not the best filter components. Probably saturating like heck. However, why does this matter? The input is low power-factor. So what? So are most electronics. The output is noisy. So what? It's not connected to the PHEV. At worst, it could cause arcing in the water pump motor.

Sure, there is radio interference, but my garage is full of other electronics that works just fine - except LED bulbs, which do sometimes flicker very very slightly when I dim the bulbs and use the water pump at the same time. Is this a clue?

I should note that the BMW 530e on-board charger is [known to be temperamental](https://www.speakev.com/threads/bmw-530e-fails-to-charge.127816/). It seems to have many conceptual errors in its design, just as LED dimmers do (the whole idea of chopping an AC waveform and using that as a signal to another PWM seems flaky to me). But I suppose I shouldn't go blaming the victim. Clearly the variable speed drive is playing an aggressor role here. The question is, what is the mechanism? Power quality issue? Radio interference?

Comment: Sometimes difficult to know why a device influences in another, so you have to try to mitigate interferences. Probably the main problem is the AC supply, I suggest to check cross section of wires to car charger; use a single phase EMC/EMI filter for the supply of pump VFD (I have used Schaffner, but there are many others); use shielded cable from EMC filter to reactors and to VFD input. Check earth wire to the VFD and motor. Also using a shielded cable from VFD to motor, symetrical type better, will help.

Comment: @Bravale. The grounding looks fine, and I am already using shielded cable to the motor. Your suggestion about EMC/EMI filtering makes a lot of sense. I have added 1 more capacitor, to make my input filter more similar to the type of product you suggested. But with lower resonance (350Hz) to be sure I catch the PWM noise. I will report back in 2-3 days on results (it takes a while because the symptoms are intermittent).

Comment: @Bravale. Indeed, the problem appears to be easily solved using an EMI filter similar to the ones you pointed me to. I've updated the question accordingly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a standard EMI filter or just a capacitor (as suggested in my other answer) gets rid of maybe 20-50% of the noise. If this works, it is cost effective.

However, there is nothing wrong with input reactors *per se*. When properly sized, they get rid of 100% of the powerline noise (i.e., my scope can't detect it any more).

The problem is that (lured by its low cost and small size) I fell into the common trap of assuming that a 2mH *common mode choke* behaves like a 2mH inductor. After all, the 2mH CMC (left: CMT908-V1) weighs just 1oz and costs $10, while a real 1mH inductor (right: 72#14awg on
[Magnetics XFlux 0078617A7](https://www.mag-inc.com/Media/Magnetics/Datasheets/0078617A7.pdf)) weighs 16oz and costs $30 of materials plus 1 hour of labor.

[image: inductor size comparison]

The problem is that CMCs are rated for *difference mode current in common mode configuration*. For the CMC pictured above (which was the one in the question) the magnetics are selected for 200mA *common mode* current, while the CMC is rated for 7.5A. In other words, it is assumed that the inductor is successfully filtering out common-mode noise, leaving very little common mode current.

Of course, this concept doesn't work if the noise is *differential*, such as in a variable speed drive. Then you run into saturation very quickly. As shown in the test below with a 10V pulse, the CMT908-V1's inductance drops to 4 microhenries at just 2A (one active winding only). It might as well not be there at all.

[image: CMT908-V1 performance]
(Test of CMT908-V1. Blue curve: inverted driving voltage. Yellow curve: voltage on a 0.1 ohm series resistor. Clipping is due to display range, and slight oscillation after turn-off is due to resonance with driving transistor.)

Sadly, the CMT908-V1 datasheet does not mention the common-mode saturation current anywhere. Industry secret, I guess?

By contrast, feeding the same 10V pulse into the inductor on the right, it's a nearly constant 1mH all the way up to 40A (the pulse weakens somewhat due to the current measurement resistor, but the slope of the yellow line also reduces correspondingly). Which handles the ripple peaks for a 7A RMS bridge rectifier input.

[image: XFlux performance]
(Test of XFlux inductor. Blue curve: inverted driving voltage. Yellow curve: voltage on a 0.1 ohm series resistor. Note the 100X longer timescale and 10X higher current scale compared to the CMT908-V1 test!)

In summary, fixing the input reactor is much more effective than merely adding more capacitance to the VFD, as a good input reactor effectively creates a quadratic (LC) filter. Unlike the capacitor-only solution, the improved input reactor appears to completely vanquish the power line noise. Making it cost effective may require adding stages and/or shrinking the inductor to minimum required performance. But the effectiveness of a sufficiently sized input reactor can't be denied.

Comment: FYI, typical CMCs for power line application saturate in the 10-100mA range (-30% L), give or take rating and material type.  Under a few amperes, the core will indeed be ~nonexistent.

Comment: @Tim Indeed, that seems to be my experience (I've tested many CMCs now). I also read many datasheets on these parts, and electronics textbooks, and swear I never saw this very basic issue mentioned. Curious.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by user Bravale, a standard EMI filter design might be required. So I inserted the DM/CM capacitors shown below (in the red circle). After this change, 1 week has elapsed without any sign of the issue.

[image: EMI filtering]

(note: for an added layer of safety if your 240V is balanced, I would recommend splitting the 47nF capacitor into one 22nF capacitor on each line. That way the chassis won't be at a very high voltage should its ground bond fail).

It's possible that chokes alone could be sufficient, as many companies sell "input reactors" that are just chokes. In my case, chokes alone didn't work. My hypothesis is that the chokes I'm using are not really designed for DM/CM configuration, and therefore have low saturation currents, and therefore don't do much (when confronted with large ripple currents due to large electrolytics inside the VFD). In any case, the standard LC EMI filters are much more economical than any inductor-only solution.

It is surprising to me that a PHEV would be sensitive to a 20kHz signal of such low power that a 1 uF capacitor takes care of it. I would think that the car's onboard 4KW charger would have much larger signals inside of it!

Comment: The way to use DM chokes is *not* as shown in the sketch, but "both dots" either facing input or output.

Comment: @greybeard Both dots facing input or output would be a Common Mode choke. There would be no effect on Difference Mode noise because the same EMF would be added to both lines. So the voltage between lines remains (L1+EMF)-(L2+EMF) = L1-L2 on both sides of the choke. Having said that, I acknowledge that the part I am using is branded as a Common Mode choke, and therefore I am abusing it (probably causing saturation) by trying to use it in Difference Mode. (But I can't be sure, given the lack of manufacturer specs.)

Comment: Both halves of a choke carrying the same current (say, \$I_{L1}\$) is either doubling flux, or cancelling out. No difference involved. (What EMF?)

Comment: @greybeard "Both halves of a choke carrying the same current is either doubling flux, or cancelling out". Correct. Difference Mode / Common Mode refers to the type of noise that is isolated. EMF is the L x di/dt voltage which shows up on all windings. It either doubles or cancels out, depending on the configuration. In a Common Mode configuration (with both dots facing the input or output) the EMFs cancel out so that the Difference Mode noise is not isolated. While a Difference Mode configuration (or combined DM/CM as I had initially) causes inexpensive Common Mode chokes to saturate.